# Simple find_package config file example

Tags: cmake

Now I have a lib I made my self that I want to use in another CMake c++ project. It exists in my computer like this.

```
${MY_LIB_PATH}\include
${MY_LIB_PATH}\lib\x86\debug\lib-files
${MY_LIB_PATH}\lib\x86\release\lib-files
${MY_LIB_PATH}\lib\x64\debug\lib-files
${MY_LIB_PATH}\lib\x64\release\lib-files
```

What would a basic config file be like which makes CMake `find_package` know those? I expected it would be very simple because it just doesn't have much information to provide. [But this page just make my head hurt.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html)

Sorry, I decided to copy the source code around so I don't really know which answer should be accepted.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file)?

Answer (score 33):

Don't write a config yourself; use CMake's `export` command.  It's too broad to cover here in its entirety, but here's a modified example from one of my projects:

```
install(TARGETS
        your_target
    EXPORT YourPackageConfig
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
)
export(TARGETS
        your_target
    NAMESPACE YourPackage::
    FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/YourPackageConfig.cmake"
)
install(EXPORT
        YourPackageConfig
    DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/YourPackage/cmake"
    NAMESPACE YourPackage::
)
```

This will create the config file for you, so other projects can use it via `find_package`.

```
find_package(YourPackage REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(foo YouprPackage::your_target)
```

This handles the `IMPORTED` targets automatically, and also lets you embed compiler flags, include paths, library dependencies, and even which files are part of your interface (basically, anything that falls under the `INTERFACE` properties).

Comment: Are you sure this works? The manual of the export command says "The file created by this command is specific to the build tree and should never be installed". And indeed, if I try to do this, I get an error message saying "The file ... was generated by the export() command.  It may not be installed with the install() command".

Comment: @GeorgP. - Which command is giving you that problem?  The file created by `export` (`${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/YourPackageConfig.cmake`) isn't the same as the one being installed (`${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/YourPackage/cmake`).

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. But what is YourPackageConfig.cmake then used for anyway?

Comment: This snippet will create two files, both named `YourPackageConfig.cmake`, just in different locations.  The one created by `export` lets other packages consume your artifacts without having to install them first, although I've never used this outside of a brief test; I find `make && make install` much cleaner, and it matches the more common usage of any packages I'm working on.

Comment: Ah, this is really awesome! This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve, provide both options for the user. But how would the user's CMakeList.txt file look if he tries to use the library without installing it? The same? Or would he use `add_subdirectory` instead of `find_package()`?

Comment: No, you'd still need `find_package`.  You'd configure the project with something like `cmake project_src -DYourPackage_DIR=/path/to/YourProject_build_dir`.  As far as I'm aware, anytime you're dealing with config files, it's for projects that are built independently.

Comment: So how shall I use it? Having the project as a git submodule I must go to the directory of the project and generate the `YourPackageConfig.cmake` by calling `cmake .` and then `find_package(YourPackage CONFIG REQUIRED)` will work only? Or is there another way do to that?

Comment: @K.Koovalsky - Config files are designed to be used with built artifacts.  You don't have to necessarily install it after building, although I prefer that approach.  If you're putting your dependencies in submodules, I don't know of any way to leverage the config files while also using submodules, so if that's your goal you might have to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, then I don't really understand the basic usage for this scenario. The approach you (@StephenNewell) propose is preferred for projects compiled in their root tree, which may be installed in the system-reachable path?

Comment: @K.Koovalsky - The question was about writing a package configuration file to use with cmake; these files are used when you're building a project, then using those artifacts in a different project.  This doesn't require installing projects, let alone system-wide, although the latter option is the simplest pattern to follow.  If you want to use dependencies as sub-modules with config files (I think that's what you were asking about in your previous comment), then you'll need to ask a new question; I don't know how to solve that problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the export path be `${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR}/cmake/YourPackage`? Since for the standard case of system wide installation, this would put it in `/usr/share/cmake/YourPackage`, where it is found by cmake. This is e.g. what pybind11 does.

Comment: @MaxNoe - As long as its part of the standard search path (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#search-procedure), you can use whatever you want.  If anything, I should probably change this to install to the lib folder, since you may need a different config file for different architectures.

Comment: Would be useful to link to [the relevant docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/guide/importing-exporting/index.html).

Comment: I am following this example and it works just except that the consumer library is showing this error "Target consumer_target links to target lib_used_by_the_imported_package but the target wast not found. Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an alias is missing?" This is basically a transitive dependency that I do not need to be aware of at the consumer package. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @Eslam - Whoever wrote your exported library probably didn't specify `PUBLIC` or `INTERFACE` when linking against whatever `lib_used_by_the_imported_package`.  Open a question with a [mcve] if you need help.

Comment: @StephenNewell In fact, I happen to be the writer of the imported package and I have also specified `PUBLIC`  in both `target_include_directories()` and `target_link_libraries()`. Anything else to check?

Comment: @Eslam - Your best bet is to ask a new question to get some eyes on your problem.

Comment: I figured what's wrong. In the library that is meant to be consumed, link it against protobuf by using the cmake variable  `${PROTOBUF_LIBRARY}` rather than using the target that is enclosed in the namespace `protobuf::libprotobuf`

Answer (score 8):

Put a "${libname}-config.cmake" in library's root.

Then add an IMPORTED target in that file.

There is a example for libprotobuf.

```
add_library(libprotobuf STATIC IMPORTED GLOBAL)

set_target_properties(libprotobuf PROPERTIES 
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/prebuilt/android/${ANDROID_ABI}/libprotobuf.a"
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES "${ZLIB_LIBRARIES};${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")
```

Set Env or CMake variable "${libname}_DIR" to "${MY_LIB_PATH}"

Use it.

```
find_package(${libname})
#.......
target_link_libraries(main ${libname})
```

Comment: Why these kind of advices are not in official docs? Why they have to be so awful (docs)? Thx btw -- simple and works. Also I suggest using CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR instead of CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR to make this subproject relocatable.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this [older doc](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-to-create-a-ProjectConfig.cmake-file) could be a tad more lightweight. And there is also this [tutorial](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/tutorials/Packaging) or [this other one](https://coderwall.com/p/y3zzbq/use-cmake-enabled-libraries-in-your-cmake-project). The last one is perhaps the simplest.

Hope to not have added more pain :-)

Following the docs should give something roughly like the following (supposing your library is `mylib`):

#### MyLib/MyLibConfig.cmake.in

```
# - Config file for the MyLib package
# It defines the following variables
#  MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS - include directories for MyLib
#  MYLIB_LIBRARIES    - libraries to link against
#  MYLIB_EXECUTABLE   - the bar executable

# Compute paths
get_filename_component(MYLIB_CMAKE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
set(MYLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS "@CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS@")

# Our library dependencies (contains definitions for IMPORTED targets)
if(NOT TARGET mylib AND NOT MyLib_BINARY_DIR)
  include("${MYLIB_CMAKE_DIR}/MyLibTargets.cmake")
endif()

# These are IMPORTED targets created by MyLibTargets.cmake
set(MYLIB_LIBRARIES mylib)
```

#### MyLib/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake.in

```
set(PACKAGE_VERSION "@MYLIB_VERSION@")

# Check whether the requested PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION is compatible
if("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_LESS "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE FALSE)
else()
  set(PACKAGE_VERSION_COMPATIBLE TRUE)
  if ("${PACKAGE_VERSION}" VERSION_EQUAL "${PACKAGE_FIND_VERSION}")
    set(PACKAGE_VERSION_EXACT TRUE)
  endif()
endif()
```

#### main MyLib/CMakeLists.txt

```
...

set(MYLIB_MAJOR_VERSION 0)
set(MYLIB_MINOR_VERSION 1)
set(MYLIB_PATCH_VERSION 0)
set(MYLIB_VERSION
  ${MYLIB_MAJOR_VERSION}.${MYLIB_MINOR_VERSION}.${MYLIB_PATCH_VERSION})

...

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.c ...)

...

install(TARGETS mylib
  # IMPORTANT: Add the mylib library to the "export-set"
  EXPORT MyLibTargets
  RUNTIME DESTINATION "${INSTALL_BIN_DIR}" COMPONENT bin
  LIBRARY DESTINATION "${INSTALL_LIB_DIR}" COMPONENT shlib
  PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}/mylib"
    COMPONENT dev)

...

# The interesting stuff goes here
# ===============================

# Add all targets to the build-tree export set
export(TARGETS mylib
  FILE "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibTargets.cmake")

# Export the package for use from the build-tree
# (this registers the build-tree with a global CMake-registry)
export(PACKAGE MyLib)

# Create the MyLibConfig.cmake and MyLibConfigVersion files
file(RELATIVE_PATH REL_INCLUDE_DIR "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}"
   "${INSTALL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
# ... for the build tree
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}" "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}")
configure_file(MyLibConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfig.cmake" @ONLY)
# ... for the install tree
set(CONF_INCLUDE_DIRS "\${MYLIB_CMAKE_DIR}/${REL_INCLUDE_DIR}")
configure_file(MyLibConfig.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/MyLibConfig.cmake" @ONLY)
# ... for both
configure_file(MyLibConfigVersion.cmake.in
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake" @ONLY)

# Install the MyLibConfig.cmake and MyLibConfigVersion.cmake
install(FILES
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}${CMAKE_FILES_DIRECTORY}/MyLibConfig.cmake"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/MyLibConfigVersion.cmake"
  DESTINATION "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)

# Install the export set for use with the install-tree
install(EXPORT MyLibTargets DESTINATION
  "${INSTALL_CMAKE_DIR}" COMPONENT dev)
```