# Creating a package config file from an already compliled library?

Tags: cmake

This questions is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857596/cmake-simple-config-file-example), but I believe the last one was concerning a library made by the user. I have an already-compiled project called `FooBar` that comes with two libraries, `Foo` and `Bar`. All that I have is: `foo.h` and `foo.so`, `bar.h` and `bar.so`. I want to be able to call it from another CMake project:

```
find_package(Foo)
find_package(Bar)
target_link_libraries(FooBar::Foo)
target_link_libraries(FooBar::Bar)
```

How can I go about creating a `FooBarConfig.cmake` that imports both of these libraries and makes them accessible from the outside world? All tutorials online show the creation of a `CMakeLists.txt` file and generating files. I don't have the source code. All I have is the compiled code. What can I do?

Comment: What is wrong with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49857853/3440745) as example?

Comment: @Tsyvarev I know I'm doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find out how to do `FooBar::Bar`. It works fine when I add a single library such as `Foo`, but I can't seem to find out how to do it to create the `FooBar::Foo` way of things.

Comment: `FooBar::Foo`, FooBar::Bar, `Foo` are just names of the library targets, which can be created with `add_library()` command.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for clarifying these points.