# MINIMAL cmake example that creates a package that other projects can use with find_package()

Tags: cmake

I'm looking for a minimal example (without all kinds of bloat) of how to properly set up and install a package for a custom library that enables other cmake projects to use it via find_package(). Every example I can find is convoluted and conflicts with other examples.

Let's say my project is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(my_project VERSION 1.0)

include_directories(include)

add_library(my_lib SHARED my_lib.cpp)

install(TARGETS my_lib LIBRARY DESTINATION "lib")

install(DIRECTORY "include/" DESTINATION "include")
```

How do I minimally package this up so that, in another project, I can use `find_package(my_project)`?

I've seen examples that use `export()`, and others that use `configure_package_config_file()`. The latter specifies that you need to create a `*.cmake.in` file, and I can't find any documentation on what would need to go in the `*.cmake.in` file.

Thanks!

Comment: On Stack Overflow we don't write tutorials, guides, examples. If you don't know which tutorial is follow when installing your package, then you could choose CMake official one: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/Adding%20Export%20Configuration.html. Would you face some problems when following it, then ask **specifically** about that problems.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cmake simple config file example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857596/cmake-simple-config-file-example)