# cmake: How to package c/c++ code which can then be used in another c/c++ code (Windows)?

Tags: c++, c, windows

### Background

The following is a simple 2-step approach to begin understanding how to use shared and/or static libraries on Windows for c/c++ programs with cmake.

- It works on Ubuntu (WSL) using g++.
- It fails on Windows using the Developer Power Shell (via opening the project in Visual Studio 2022).

### Question

1. After following the steps outlined below, I get the following linker error. How should the CMakeLists.txt file(s) be modified address this Windows error?

> \CreateSharedLibs\UseLib..\CreateLib\build\lib\MathFunctions.dll : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x340

2. Should additional changes to CMakeLists.txt file(s) be made to better follow conventions or avoid errors (e.g., find_library should be used - if so how?)?

### How to test

First build process in `CreateLib` folder and then do the exact same thing in `UsedLib` folder. On linux this is via the terminal, on Windows you can open the folder in Visual Studio and then use the Developer Power Shell.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build .
```

### Code

Project code is available via [GitHub](https://github.com/greenwoodms06/LearningCode) as well.

**Code structure**

```
CreateLib
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - src
      - MathFunctions.cpp
   - include
      - MathFunctions.h
UseLib
   - CMakeLists.txt
   - src
      - main.cpp
```

---

**CreateLib Files**
CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MathFunctionsProject)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

# Set the output directory for the DLL
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

# Add the include directory
include_directories(include)

# Define location of source files
set(SOURCE_FILES src/MathFunctions.cpp)

# Create the shared library
add_library(MathFunctions SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Set the name and properties of the shared library
set_target_properties(MathFunctions PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "MathFunctions" PREFIX "")

# Copy the DLL to the output directory
add_custom_command(TARGET MathFunctions POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:MathFunctions> ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
)
```

MathFunctions.h

```cpp
#ifndef MATHFUNCTIONS_H
#define MATHFUNCTIONS_H

double sqrt_custom(double x);

#endif
```

MathFuntions.cpp

```cpp
#include "MathFunctions.h"
#include <cmath>

double sqrt_custom(double x) {
        return std::sqrt(x);
    }
```

---

**UseLib Files**

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(SquareRootApp)

# Set the output directory for the executable
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Create the executable and link against the DLL
add_executable(SquareRootApp src/main.cpp)

# Link the executable with the DLL
IF (WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(SquareRootApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/build/lib/MathFunctions.dll)
ELSE()
  target_link_libraries(SquareRootApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/build/lib/MathFunctions.so)
ENDIF()

# Include the directory containing the header files
target_include_directories(SquareRootApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/include)
```

MathFuntions.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MathFunctions.h"

int main() {
    double x = 16.0;
    double result = sqrt_custom(x);

    std::cout << "Square root of " << x << " is: " << result << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know Windows and can't help directly, but you're going to be better served long term by letting cmake handle the details using export and `find_package`.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857596/simple-find-package-config-file-example/49858236#49858236

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue arises from the need to `link` to a `.lib`. Don't try to link to a `.dll`!!! Once you link to a `.lib` then the `.dll` should be copied over to the location of the `.exe` generated from the second step (i.e., `UseLib` step).

Changes to both `CMakeLists.txt` was required. The changes have also been pushed to the repo in the OP.

1. `CreateLib\CMakeLists.txt` - Make sure to copy the linker file (.lib)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(MathFunctionsProject)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

# Set the output directory for the DLL
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)

# Add the include directory
include_directories(include)

# Define location of source files
set(SOURCE_FILES src/MathFunctions.cpp)

# Create the shared library
add_library(MathFunctions SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})

# Set the name and properties of the shared library
set_target_properties(MathFunctions PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "MathFunctions" PREFIX "" WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)

# Copy the DLL and LIB to the output directory
add_custom_command(TARGET MathFunctions POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_FILE:MathFunctions> ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy $<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:MathFunctions> ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY} // Added this line
)
```

2. `UseLib\CMakeLists.txt` - Make sure to target the linker file (.lib) and copy over the .dll

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(SquareRootApp)

# Set the output directory for the executable
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)

# Create the executable and link against the DLL
add_executable(SquareRootApp src/main.cpp)

# Link the executable with the LIB and copy the DLL to the executable path
IF (WIN32) // Modified this section
  target_link_libraries(SquareRootApp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/build/lib/MathFunctions.lib)
  set(MATHFUNCTIONS_DLL ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/build/lib/MathFunctions.dll)
  add_custom_command(TARGET SquareRootApp POST_BUILD
                   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
                   ${MATHFUNCTIONS_DLL} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:SquareRootApp>)
ELSE()
  target_link_libraries(SquareRootApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/build/lib/MathFunctions.so)
ENDIF()

# Include the directory containing the header files
target_include_directories(SquareRootApp PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../CreateLib/include)
```