Two ways to create CMakeLists.txt file for a library with no sources but with headers
UPDATE (TRIVIAL ANSWER)
Silly me, the first only works for me because the libraries are on my system also. I need to use the second method. It's a shame that IMPORTED_LOCATION cannot be a list. The INTERFACE library works fine for the build but fails at the INSTALL command (No error message, library is just not installed)
OLD POST
I have a library libfoo.so and want to provide it to other projects by wrapping it into a cmake project. I know two ways of achieving this via a CMakeLists.txt file. First method is the following:
add_library(foo-imported INTERFACE)
target_include_directories(foo-imported INTERFACE include)
target_link_directories(foo-imported INTERFACE lib)
target_link_libraries (foo-imported INTERFACE foo )

And this is the second way I know of:
add_library (foo SHARED IMPORTED GLOBAL)
set_target_properties(foo PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION  lib/libfoo.so
    IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES "CXX")
target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE include)

which one is the recommended method and why?
Are there even better ways to accomplish this?
Update I am happy with the answer to the second question that Stephen Nevell gave in his comment.
I want to rephrase the first question (which is irrelevant to what I want to achieve and BTW, I often ask questions without wanting to achieve anything). The remaining question now is, under which circumstances would you use the first set of functions and when the second. I think the answer to this question may bring a few more light rays (or at least photons) into the thinking of the cmake creators

If the library is header-only, why would you even need a build step?

The recommended way would be to use export on the original library, so that way dependent projects can use find_package.  Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857596/simple-find-package-config-file-example/49858236#49858236

@super, I am not aware of a build step and I am certain this is not a header only library. It is more like a cpp-missing library.

@Stepen Newell, I would definitely not do this if I had the original source code. But you are correct, cmake export would be a third way to do this.  In my cmake add_subdirectory setup I do not want to introduce find_package right now though. But yes, your are making a good point.

Please, add details to your question post, not to the comments. In the current form of the question post it is unclear what exactly do you want to achieve by those code snippets, so we cannot say what is recommended way. Moreover, on Stack Overflow we rarely answer with the best way. Instead, our answers provide possible ways. It is up to you to choose the one which is most suitable for you.
